# Layout alignment of spinner and TextView in LinearLayout programmatically android

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, android-spinner, android-xml

I want to achieve this layout below as shown in the image below...**example -spinner1 then text1  then new line spinner2 then text2 and so on**....every thing is fine I just want to arrange the layout correctly..I attached both the images with I want and which is currently showing with the code.

I want layout like this below image

[image]

but currently its showing like this below-

[image]

**Bookdetails.java**

```
public class Bookdetails extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bookdetails);


        final ArrayList<String> spinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        spinnerArray.add("Yes");
        spinnerArray.add("No");


        final String seat1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("seat1");
        final String seat2 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("seat2");
        final String seat3 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("seat3");
        final String seat4 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("seat4");
        final String seat5 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("seat5");
        final String seat6 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("seat6");
        Log.i("seats", seat1+seat2+seat3+seat4+seat5+seat6);
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, seat1+seat2+seat3+seat4+seat5+seat6, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();

        final int N = 6; 

        final TextView[] myTextViews = new TextView[N]; 
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
        //setContentView(ll);
        if(!(seat1==null)){
            final TextView rowTextView = new TextView(this);
            rowTextView.setText("Seat selected" + seat1);
            ll.addView(rowTextView);

            //<------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
            Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
            ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);
            spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), spinnerArray.get(arg2).toString()+""+seat1, 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
            ll.addView(spinner);

            //<------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
        }
        if(!(seat2==null)){
            final TextView rowTextView = new TextView(this);
            rowTextView.setText("Seat selected" + seat2);
            ll.addView(rowTextView);
            //<------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
            Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
            ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);
            spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), spinnerArray.get(arg2).toString()+""+seat2, 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
            ll.addView(spinner);

            //<------------------------------------------------------------------------------>

        }
        if(!(seat3==null)){
            final TextView rowTextView = new TextView(this);
            rowTextView.setText("Seat selected" + seat3 );
            ll.addView(rowTextView);
            //<------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
            Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
            ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);
            spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), spinnerArray.get(arg2).toString()+""+seat3, 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
            ll.addView(spinner);

            //<------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
        }
        if(!(seat4==null)){
            final TextView rowTextView = new TextView(this);
            rowTextView.setText("Seat selected"+ seat4  );
            ll.addView(rowTextView);
            //<------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
            Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
            ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);
            spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), spinnerArray.get(arg2).toString()+""+seat4, 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
            ll.addView(spinner);

            //<------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
        }
        if(!(seat5==null)){
            final TextView rowTextView = new TextView(this);
            rowTextView.setText("Seat selected"+ seat5  );
            ll.addView(rowTextView);
            //<------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
            Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
            ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);
            spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), spinnerArray.get(arg2).toString()+""+seat5, 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
            ll.addView(spinner);

            //<------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
        }
        if(!(seat6==null)){
            final TextView rowTextView = new TextView(this);
            rowTextView.setText("Seat selected"+ seat6  );
            ll.addView(rowTextView);
            //<------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
            Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
            ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);
            spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), spinnerArray.get(arg2).toString()+""+seat6, 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
            ll.addView(spinner);

            //<------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
        }

    }
}
```

**bookdetails.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is dynamic then use listView and spinner,textview as the list item from xml file.

Also from the previous activity to next activity, pass data as parcelable array list. That would help..

Comment: the data and all are correct i need help in layouts see the image output which i am getting and see what i want in the pictures which i uploaded.

Comment: your layout orientation is vertical, make it horizontal will solve this.

Comment: create different layout for different seats in horizontal orientation and add all those in your xml layout.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Linearlayout` with horizontal orientation which contains one spinner and text view.

And inflate that layout instead of creating `Spinner` programatically.

```
LinearLayout layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, parent, false);
ll.addView(layout);
```

**Update**

```
if(seat1!=null){
        LinearLayout customLayout = (LinearLayout)layoutInflater.inflate(R.id.customLayout, ll, false)
        final TextView rowTextView = (TextView)customLayout.findViewById(R.id.textView)
        rowTextView.setText("Seat selected" + seat1);
        //<------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)customLayout.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), spinnerArray.get(arg2).toString()+""+seat1, 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        ll.addView(customLayout);
}
```

Comment: Updated the code for only first condition, rest you can do by yourself. It's pretty easy :)

Comment: its not happening..its showing ..Type mismatch: cannot convert from View to LinearLayout

Comment: I have updated the code. Check the second line, cast it to LinearLayout.

Answer (score -1):

For every

```
if(!(seat1==null)){
}
```

do the following

```
        final TextView rowTextView = new TextView(this);
        rowTextView.setText("Seat selected" + seat1);

        //<------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
        Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), spinnerArray.get(arg2).toString()+""+seat1, 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        linearLayout.addView(spinner);
        linearLayout.addView(rowTextView);
        ll.addView(linearLayout);
```